# Issue while doing git merge

Tags: git, merge

1. **develop**  => main  branch now
2. **credit**  => new branch made from develop branch  for credit changes
3. now edited **develop branch** code and removed credit related changes/codes, so now  **develop branch** doesn't contain credit related codes ....
4. **dev-plus-credit**  => new branch made from  develop, this branch will be used to integrate/merge code from develop and credit branch

*command i used*

[now on *develop*]
`git checkout credit`

[now on *credit*]
`git checkout develop`

[now on *develop*]
`git flow feature start remove-credit-part`

.. changes/git add/commit

`git flow feature finish remove-credit-part`

... now credit part is removed from develop branch and develop branch doesn't contain credit part now ...

`git checkout -b dev-plus-credit`

[now on *dev-plus-credit*]

`git merge develop`

`git merge credit`

Do you think i am doing something wrong here? Please point out, i will be happy to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b dev-plus-credit
git merge develop
```

That should not do much, considering `dev-plus-credit` was just created from `develop`, meaning its HEAD is already at `develop` HEAD.

You only need the second merge (`git merge credit`).

That second merge might trigger merge conflict though, considering

---

The [OP TheRarer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9460570/therarer) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946488/issue-while-doing-git-merge/62948353#comment111391168_62948353):

> I solved it by making new branch from develop itself and manually adding the code from `credit` branch.

Comment: hi, i did this ..
```git checkout -b dev-plus-credit```
```git merge develop```
```git merge credit```
but credit changes not seen in  **dev-plus-credit**  branch. 
It just says .. already upto date.

Comment: @TheRarer That is expected if you have not done any new commits in the credit branch.

Comment: let me try with that .. i am stuck in this since yesterday.

Comment: not working .. i am bit stressed now. Thank u for your comment though.

Comment: @TheRarer Did you commit in credit branch (after modifying a file), and then merge to dev-plus-credit?

Comment: yes, i removed a semicolon and tried merging and it shows conflict at that line. But other codes from credit are not coming other than that line infact. Now i am wondering what mistake did i made while making branches or somewhere else.

Comment: @TheRarer other codes should show up once you have resolved the conflict. Or those changes were done too soon (before creating the other branches)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218011/discussion-between-therarer-and-vonc).

Comment: @TheRarer Sorry for the delay. I am in the chat.

Comment: sorry i ended that day quick. I solved it by making new branch from develop itself and manually adding the code from credit branch. I am very grateful that you tried to help me. Thank you again.

Comment: @TheRarer Great! I have updated my answer accordingly.